# Drop filter on hover action

Tags: css

I have a map wher I want to add gray filter and remove it when mouse hover map. So I do class like this:

```
.profile-pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* border-radius: 50%; */
  box-shadow: #222 0.2em 0.2em 1em;

  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(135%) contrast(120%);

  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
.profile-pic:hover .profile-pic:focus {
  -webkit-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: #224 0.2em 0.2em 0.6em 0.1em;
}
```

But is like focus event don't works, can someone take a look what happen there:

There is complete approach of it: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vn4gu5z6/)

Comment: you need to keep `,` between the css selector as shown `.profile-pic:hover, .profile-pic:focus`

Comment: @pedroI think you are missing a comma ;) Check the last CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a comma between the selector

`.profile-pic:hover, .profile-pic:focus`

And here is a fiddle for you [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/joLqvqyd/)